# Adding a span element with absolute position using Javascript gives increased height

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Upon clicking on one of the rounded rectangles in the following code, it is required to create a copy of the span element and place it on top of the original element. The code does that, but the new element has an increased height. Please suggest what could go wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>

<div id="phrasesDiv" style="line-height:250%" /></div>

<style type="text/css">
.phrase {
    font-size:18pt;
    color:blue;
    background: palegreen;
    border:2px solid green;
    padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

{
    // create the phrase list dynamically
    var phraseList = "Apple~Orange~Kiwi~Guava";
    var phrasesDiv = document.getElementById("phrasesDiv");
    var phrases = phraseList.split('~');
    for (var i=0; i<phrases.length; i++)
        phrasesDiv.innerHTML += "<span id=\""+phrases[i]+"\" class=\"phrase\" onmousedown=\"phraseTouched('"+phrases[i]+"')\">"+phrases[i]+"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
}

function getDim(el) {
    var lw = el.offsetWidth;
    var lh = el.offsetHeight;
    for (var lx=0, ly=0; el != null; lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
    return {x:lx,y:ly,w:lw,h:lh};
}

function phraseTouched(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var dim = getDim(elem);
    var dragElem = document.createElement('span')
    dragElem.id = id+"_copy";
    dragElem.innerHTML = id;
    dragElem.className += " phrase";
    dragElem.style.background = "pink";
    dragElem.style.position = "absolute";
    dragElem.style.left =  dim.x+"px";
    dragElem.style.top =  dim.y+"px";
    elem.parentNode.appendChild(dragElem);
}

</script>

</html>
```

EDIT: The following function worked ... but I am still curious to know why am I getting an increased height if I add to the div programatically.

```
function phraseTouched(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id); 
    var dim = getDim(elem); 
    document.body.innerHTML += "<span id=\"_"+id+"\" class=\"phraseDrag\" style=\"left:"+dim.x+"px;top:"+dim.y+"px;position:absolute;\">"+id+" </span>\n";  
}
```

Comment: you better make a working demo on jsfiddle.net and paste the link here so more people can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you break out the standard layout model when you add that nasty "position: absolute" property to your element and it doesn't know how to represent itself. If you want to maintain most of the styling, the easiest fix would be to simply add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

somewhere in your .phrase style, at least that's what I would do.
Of course Vijay's solution works as well as long as you don't mind losing that line-height property.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is OK. Just removed the **line-height of 250%**. Also Changed the Markup to **W3C Standard (Not Fully)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .phrase {
                font-size:18pt;
                color:blue;
                background: palegreen;
                border:2px solid green;
                padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="phrasesDiv"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // create the phrase list dynamically
            var phraseList = "Apple~Orange~Kiwi~Guava";
            var phrasesDiv = document.getElementById("phrasesDiv");
            var phrases = phraseList.split('~');
            for (var i=0; i<phrases.length; i++)
                phrasesDiv.innerHTML += "<span id=\""+phrases[i]+"\" class=\"phrase\" onmousedown=\"phraseTouched('"+phrases[i]+"')\">"+phrases[i]+"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

            function getDim(el) {
                var lw = el.offsetWidth;
                var lh = el.offsetHeight;
                for (var lx=0, ly=0; el != null; lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
                return {x:lx,y:ly,w:lw,h:lh};
            }

            function phraseTouched(id) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(id);
                var dim = getDim(elem);
                var dragElem = document.createElement('span')
                dragElem.id = id+"_copy";
                dragElem.innerHTML = id;
                dragElem.className += " phrase";
                dragElem.style.background = "pink";
                dragElem.style.position = "absolute";
                dragElem.style.left =  dim.x+"px";
                dragElem.style.top =  dim.y+"px";
                elem.parentNode.appendChild(dragElem);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** : Without removing line-height. Added line-height for each replaced span tags.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .phrase {
                font-size:18pt;
                color:blue;
                background: palegreen;
                border:2px solid green;
                padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:100%;width:500px;border:1px solid #B0B0B0;">
            <div id="phrasesDiv" style="line-height:250%;"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // create the phrase list dynamically
            var phraseList = "Apple~Orange~Kiwi~Guava~Test1~Test2~Test3~Test4~Test5~Test6~Test7~Test8~Test9~Test10";
            var phrasesDiv = document.getElementById("phrasesDiv");
            var phrases = phraseList.split('~');
            for (var i=0; i<phrases.length; i++)
            {
                phrasesDiv.innerHTML += "<span id=\""+phrases[i]+"\" class=\"phrase\" onmousedown=\"phraseTouched('"+phrases[i]+"')\">"+phrases[i]+"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
            }

            function getDim(el) {
                var lw = el.offsetWidth;
                var lh = el.offsetHeight;
                for (var lx=0, ly=0; el != null; lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
                return {x:lx,y:ly,w:lw,h:lh};
            }

            function phraseTouched(id) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(id);
                var dim = getDim(elem);
                var dragElem = document.createElement('span')
                dragElem.id = id+"_copy";
                dragElem.innerHTML = id;
                dragElem.className += " phrase";
                dragElem.style.background = "pink";
                dragElem.style.position = "absolute";
                dragElem.style.left =  dim.x+"px";
                dragElem.style.top =  dim.y+"px";
                dragElem.style.lineHeight = "27px";
                elem.parentNode.appendChild(dragElem);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i cant remove that 250% since if I add more tags, they wrap around and start overlapping (try adding more elements to phraseList).